# Can instance properties be added to a JavaScript prototype after a constructor function has been defined?

Tags: javascript, ruby, constructor, prototype

I'm new to `JavaScript`, and I am trying to wrap my head around `constructor` functions and `prototypes`. I have some experience with `Ruby`, so when learning new JS features I try to equate them to features they resemble in `Ruby` if at all possible.

To me it seems like `prototypes` are similar to `Ruby` classes. So my question is, is it possible to use the `className.prototype` command to add required properties to instances of the object, or is it necessary to reopen the `class`/`prototype` like in `Ruby`?

For example, say I had the following `constructor` function to create a Car prototype:

```
function Car (make,model,year) {
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
}
```

and I create a few cars:

```
myCar = new Car ("Honda", "Civic", 2015);
anotherCar = new Car ("Ford", "Focus", 2001);
```

Now let's say down the line I want new instances of Car to accept a `color` parameter (i.e. inherit a `color` property from the parent). Is it possible to do something like the following

```
Car.prototype.color = color;
```

such that when a new car is initialized, it will expect a color parameter to be passed? That is, the Car `constructor` function should now be (but without me having changed it myself):

```
function Car (make, model, year, color) {
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
    this.color = color;
}
```

and thus new instances should be initialized as follows:

```
aThirdCar = new Car("BMW","325",2008,"black");
```

Or, must I go back to the original `constructor` function and manually make these changes?

I understand that using `className.prototype.methodName` is the primary use of this feature so that all instances share a single method rather than are initialized with their own.

My interest in this functionality is for my own edification on what JS can and cannot do, as well as what can vs. should be done.

Thank you.

Comment: No no, a constructor function does not "create a prototype". A constructor **has** a prototype.  Ruby inheritance and JavaScript inheritance are **much** different.

Comment: And no, changing the prototype object has absolutely nothing to do with the formal parameter list of the constructor function. And you can't change a function after it's been defined.

Comment: [This is a pretty good resource - Kyle knows what he's writing about.](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to define a new method using prototype but not sure if you can alter the input paramers number.

car.protype.color = function() {
return "red"
}

In ruby you can both alter number of parameters as well as define a new method using metaprogrammimg

ruby_object(*args)
ruby_object.define_method()